# iOS pause between songs to exec code then resume, when app is in background

Tags: ios, background, avplayer

I am building an app which needs to play a track list, but between each song the music should pause to execute some code, then once complete the music should resume. This needs to work when the app is in the background as well as in the foreground.

I have tried a couple of methods but none seem to be able to do everything I want.

AVQueuePlayer - I can't seem to identify when any one song has stopped, only when the whole queue has stopped.

AVPlayer - I can identify when the track has ended with a notification, then I can run my extra code then load the next track. This works fine as long as the app is not in the background, when the app is in the background the code executes fine except the `[avPlayer play]` command does not work. It does not throw an error, it simply does not play. I know it has moved to the next song and loaded it into AVPlayer as I output the meta data and it has moved on.

Just to be clear the initial track does run in the background, it is only starting the next track which does not run in the background.

Code below...

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
+(void) playItem {
    //get the play item from the song array based on intSongIndex
    MPMediaItem *currentSong = [songsNowPlaying objectAtIndex:intSongIndex];
    AVPlayerItem * currentItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[currentSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]];
    [avPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:currentItem];

    //add notification to the currentItem
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:currentItem];

    //play
    [avPlayer play];

    NSArray *metadataList = [[avPlayer currentItem].asset commonMetadata];
    for (AVMetadataItem *metaItem in metadataList) {
        NSLog(@"%@: %@",[metaItem commonKey], [metaItem value]);
    }

    //increment song index so next time the next song is selected
    intSongIndex ++;
    if (intSongIndex >= songsNowPlaying.count) {
        intSongIndex = 0;
    }
}

+ (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //add code to be executed before the next song plays

     //call playItem to play the next song
    [self playItem];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, this needed adding to the initial viewDidLoad

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```